# Using a c# conditional statement to render html

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to do a conditional statement in C# for my asp.net page? I want it to be, basically:

```
if bool is true, add <a href>
```

I've got this:

```
<asp:Label ID="BenLabel" CssClass='<%#((Entry)(Container.DataItem)).HasBenform ? "EnabledEntry" : "DisabledEntry"%>' Text="Benefits Form" runat="server" />
```

In this way it changes its CSS class based on the bool value. However, is it possible for me to add a link, too? How would I code this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an `HyperLink` and then render it `Visible` based on this boolean condition.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="BenLink" Visible='<%# ((Entry)(Container.DataItem)).HasBenform %>' ... runat="server" />
```

Comment: Is not required to have a HyperLink, we can use an HtmlAnchor. The <a> tag with runat="server" becomes a server control and we can toggle visibility on the server side with the Eval statements also..

Comment: Yes, but the Hyperlink will be rendered as an HTML anchor, so I don't see your point here.

Comment: This worked, but it was more in line with what I wanted to use the Enabled Feature instead of the Visible feature (I still wanted the link text visible, just unable to be linked)

Answer (score 1):

I like to handle this sort of logic in the code behind on page_init or Page_Load.

Something like this

```
If (NeedToShowLink)
{
    Link.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    Link.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: or just `Link.Visible = NeedToShowLink`

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to render the control to client side and setting css to hide.

You can do something like below in the aspx page or suggested by Andrew.

<%if(condition)%>
<a href="http://test.com">Click me</a>

Happy Coding !!!